# Problem on running GAE app on local machine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Everytime I try to run my app on my local machine, I get the following error messages (quite long, sorry):

```
Initializing AppEngine server
2009-12-23 04:44:03.068::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2009-12-23 04:44:04.123::INFO:  jetty-6.1.x
2009-12-23 04:44:10.632::WARN:  failed projectrix
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.directGetContextClassLoader(LogFactory.java:901)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:862)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getContextClassLoaderInternal(LogFactory.java:859)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:704)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:253)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:612)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:217)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:188)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:377)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:938)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:690)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:251)
2009-12-23 04:44:10.635::WARN:  failed com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@8c4a77{/,C:\Users\Kee\Documents\Workspace\Projectrix\war}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.directGetContextClassLoader(LogFactory.java:901)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:862)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getContextClassLoaderInternal(LogFactory.java:859)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:704)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:253)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:612)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:217)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:188)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:377)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:938)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:690)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:251)
2009-12-23 04:44:10.637::WARN:  failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@6d0040
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.directGetContextClassLoader(LogFactory.java:901)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:862)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getContextClassLoaderInternal(LogFactory.java:859)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:704)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:253)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:612)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:217)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:188)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:377)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:938)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:690)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:251)
2009-12-23 04:44:10.638::WARN:  Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.directGetContextClassLoader(LogFactory.java:901)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:862)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getContextClassLoaderInternal(LogFactory.java:859)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:704)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:254)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:253)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:612)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:217)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:188)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:120)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:86)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:377)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:938)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:690)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:251)
2009-12-23 04:44:10.803::INFO:  Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Loading modules
   com.projectrix.rubricpage.rubricpage
      Validating <servlet> tags for module 'com.projectrix.rubricpage.rubricpage'
      For additional info see: file:/C:/Users/Kee/Documents/UPD%20Fourth%20Year%20-%20Second%20Semester/CS%20199/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.0.0_2.0.0.v200912062003/gwt-2.0.0/doc/helpInfo/servletMappings.html
         [WARN] Module declares a servlet class 'com.projectrix.rubricpage.addrubricpanel.service.RubricServiceImpl', but the web.xml has no corresponding declaration; please add the following lines to your web.xml:
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>rubricServiceImpl</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.projectrix.rubricpage.addrubricpanel.service.RubricServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>rubricServiceImpl</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/com.projectrix.rubricpage.rubricpage/rubric</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Localhost returns either an error page or a blank one. I wonder some of you might have encountered this before--what seems to be the problem?

Comment: FOLLOW-UP: Am I missing a JAR or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, you have pointed out correct path to App Engine SDK in your project properties?

Comment: @kee, could you tell me what you modified, please? Getting the same issue.